# Titanium Android No static method isDeviceProtectedStorage

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I build my Android app using Android SDK 25 (~/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-25/android.jar), but I get the error of

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isDeviceProtectedStorage(Landroid/content/Context;)Z in class Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat;

When I used Android Studio to analyse the .apk, I found the **isDeviceProtectedStorage()** method is in **android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat**, but not in **android/content/Context**.

This error occur when I try to integrate Google Firebase v9.8.0 module to the app.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide some more information like: Ti SDK version, are you using hyperloop or trying to create a normal module?

Comment: @Simon : Could you please provide the module link, so that we could help you.

Comment: I am creating normal module with Ti SDK 6.1.0, I am wondering why Appcelerator create apk without isDeviceProtectedStorage method in android/content/Context. If I create apk with Android Studio, I can found isDeviceProtectedStorage method in the android/content/Context.